# Android facebook sso - token ID invalid

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am new to facebook sso, i have integrated the SSO into my application using phonegap, this works fine in android emulator, at the same time when i do this application on device, am facing the error.. shows that invalid_token , but the same thing is working in emulator.

Even i have created the keystore and mapped with facebook apps and secret id...

Still the problem is not getting resolved...

I got some information that, the facebook itself having problem in android SSO, is this problem still remains.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you solve the problem?